# Finding the rotation of a pattern in a low resolution image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm currently working on a method to track physical devices on a surface using a mouse sensor.
A unique dot pattern based on a De-Brujin-Torus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_torus) is printed on the surface. This pattern consists of unique sub-patterns so the position of the device can be determined exactly.
The mouse sensor built into the device records a greyscale image with 36 by 36 pixels. Each dot of the printed pattern is round about 6 by 6 pixels in size in this image.

[image: Device on the dot pattern. Display shows what the sensor sees.]

Calculating the position is already possible, but the device has to be aligned to the pattern pretty exactly for it to work. Thus, I'd like to find out the angle of the pattern in the sensor image so I can rotate the image before calculating the position.

[image: Depiction of the problem.]

In this image you can see what I have (top row: raw sensor images, 1-3 aligned at 0 degrees, 4-6 rotated) and what I ideally need (bottom two, scaled for better visibility). I'd like to find the border lines of the pattern's dots and use those to find the rotation of the device.

I'm by no means an expert in image processing so I hope you can help me with my problem.
I have already tried a lot of different approaches including different thresholding methods, hough lines, upscaling, finding contours and edge detection - each with more or less disappointing results (like 20-30% success rate).

All of my past approaches kind of followed the same recipe:

- preprocess image (threshold, noise removal)
- find edges
- draw lines on edges
- calculate angle of each found line
- select most prominent angle

The biggest problem seems to be the very low resolution of the sensor image.

I don't need the exact angle, 5-10 degrees off should be ok. I also know it's impossible to distinguish 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees, but that's not a problem because I can find out the correct one by trial and error.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Here are some sensor images in original resolution. The red lines indicate the rotation (something like that is what I want).

The first three images are not rotated so tracking works fine:

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

The next three images are rotated, so I have to find out the angle. They are all rotated by about 30-50 degrees.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the images **separately** at best quality and resolution available please? And then provide a second copy, again separately with annotation of the line of orientation that you want to find. Thank you.

Comment: try a range filter i.e. 3x3 filter with value = max - min followed by thresholding. Then find lines and orientation of lines using hough transform.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I added the images to the original post.

Comment: Thank you - I shall get to work :-)

Comment: @user8190410: Thank you, but isn't the first step just a kind of edge detection? I have tried several edge detection methods including your suggestion but with no success. The noise gets amplified with edge detection and Hough Transform finds a lot of false positives (maybe due to the low resolution?).